# How to use aggregate function (MAX) on a varchar column that represents a season

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a report that needs to pull data related to the MAX season of a particular article. In order to do so I am needing to use the MAX function in SSMS. The issue is the data is a mix of alpha and numeric and it doesn't recognize that for instance that the prefix FW is actually after SS. Providing sample data below.

I have tried to utilize variables to no avail thus far

```
select 
    season, article
from 
    vw_onerange_nam 
where
    article = '656927'
group by 
    season, article 
having 
    season = max(season)
```

Results are:

```
season article
------ ------------------
SS2020 656927
SS2019 656927
FW2019 656927
```

I would hope to get one row of data for only SS2020 as I know that is the MAX season in this data, instead I get all three

Comment: Why don't you split the season into two values - one representing the season and the other representing the year, then order by year/season descending. Then you can do a partition on article with a simple row number allocation and select all articles with a row number of 1.

Comment: that sounds like a great idea - I am a bit new to the partition by in SQL - any brief examples?

Comment: and when you say split, I am assuming SUBSTRING?

Comment: [Here is some official doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), and [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/rownumber-function-with-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server1) is an okay starter.

Comment: Yep, [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it into two values either as part of your SELECT or in a view. When you do split it up, cast the year as an int, and you could allocate a numeric value for the season (use a CASE WHEN statement)

Comment: FW sounds to me as Fall Winter Concatenated to 2019. We will have to split the concatenated string .. What is your expected output?

Comment: you are correct.  I would expect that when I use a MAX function for example that if I have both FW2019 and SS2019 then SS2019 would come first in ASC order.  SS is Spring/Summer

Answer (score 2):

You can use TOP 1 with ORDER BY on two expressions (instead of using MAX on a single expression), like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 season, article
FROM vw_onerange_nam
WHERE article = '656927'
ORDER BY RIGHT(season,4) DESC, 
         CASE LEFT(season,2) WHEN 'SS' THEN 1 WHEN 'FW' THEN 2 END DESC
```

I did not convert the year part to numeric, because I assume it will always have 4 digits and a string would sort the same way.

If you have any other seasons besides Spring/Summer and Fall/Winter, you can add them in the CASE expression, with appropriate values in the THEN clause.

Later edit:

If you need rows for multiple articles, with the latest season for each article, you can use ROW_NUMBER like this:

```
SELECT season, article
FROM (
    SELECT season, article,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY article ORDER BY RIGHT(season,4) DESC, 
             CASE LEFT(season,2) WHEN 'SS' THEN 1 WHEN 'FW' THEN 2 END DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM vw_onerange_nam
) x
WHERE x.RowNum=1
```

Comment: I'm impressed that you worked out what "FW" and "SS" meant!

Comment: must be in the industry :)

Comment: This works but the thing is in reality the report is returning a lot more than 1 result - is this possible to do without the TOP 1?